# Responsive Carousel using Cycle2

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, carousel, jquery-cycle2

I'm working on a carousel using the [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) and [cycle2-carousel](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php) plugins.

Found a [solution here](https://github.com/malsup/cycle2/issues/68) to display variable number of items depending on resized window width.

Problem is the carousel breaks due to another slideshow.

Everything is working until the main slideshow cycles it's first slide, then on page resize the carousel only displays one slide.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/yDRj4/1/

**jQuery**

```
function buildCarousel(visibleSlides) {
    $('.caro').cycle({
        fx: 'carousel',
        speed: 600,
        slides: 'img',
        carouselVisible: visibleSlides,
        carouselFluid: true
    });
}
function buildSlideshow() {
    $('.home-slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        slides: 'img',
        timeout: 12000
    });
}

function initCycle() {
    var width = $(document).width();
    var visibleSlides = 5;

    if ( width < 400 ) {visibleSlides = 1}
    else if(width < 700) {visibleSlides = 3}
    else {visibleSlides = 5};

    buildSlideshow();
    buildCarousel(visibleSlides);
}

function reinit_cycle() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var destroyCarousel = $('.caro').cycle('destroy');

    if ( width < 400 ) {destroyCarousel;reinitCycle(1);} 
    else if ( width > 400 && width < 700 ) {destroyCarousel; reinitCycle(3);} 
    else {destroyCarousel;reinitCycle(5);}
}

function reinitCycle(visibleSlides) {
    buildCarousel(visibleSlides);
}
var reinitTimer;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(reinitTimer);
    reinitTimer = setTimeout(reinit_cycle, 100);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    initCycle();    
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='main' style="max-width: 950px;margin: auto;">
    <div class="home-slideshow" style="margin-bottom: 150px;">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://placehold.it/950x250" alt="">
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://placehold.it/950x250" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="caro" >
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""> 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""> 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is cycle2 included in that jsfiddle? I'm very confused by that in this and other fiddles. There's no link to it in the HTML.

Comment: External Resources Tab, added from a CDN
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.cycle2/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what that means-- how is it linked in to the fiddle? There's no link to the CDN.

Comment: @Aerovistae, open the Fiddle page, then click on `External Resources` tab on the side menu. You'll see a short list of resources that the fiddle uses, including `cycle2` and `carousel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, after the first slideshow transitions, when it recreates the Carousel, it is setting all of the images to have an opacity of 0.

Adding `$('.caro img').css('opacity','1');` after initializing the carousel fixed it, but I'm sure there is a better solution for this, but you might have to dig into the source of the plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/cZTxM/2/

Comment: Interesting... 
Thanks a lot, I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following line:

```
var destroyCarousel = $('.caro').cycle('destroy');
```

...which sets `destroyCarousel` to the result of that method call (a jQuery object), instead of creating a function you can call to perform the destruction.

I think this is what you meant to do:

```
function reinit_cycle() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var destroyCarousel = function() { // create a function
        $('.caro').cycle('destroy');
    }

    if (width < 400) {
        destroyCarousel(); // call the function
        reinitCycle(1);
    } else if (width > 400 && width < 700) {
        destroyCarousel();
        reinitCycle(3);
    } else {
        destroyCarousel();
        reinitCycle(5);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7eAk2/

Comment: By the way, it's *really* bad practice to create two functions in the same file named `reinitCycle` and `reinit_cycle`. You're just asking to confuse yourself.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I wasn't clear with the problem. It still breaks, if you wait till the first slideshow transitions to the next slide then try to resize the page.